# How to load information to a pyinstaller executable file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pyinstaller

I am new to python and trying to develop a solution. Here is the scenario where I am currently stuck.

---

## Background

I have 2 files both in the same directory.

1. `actualcode.py`
2. `userInformation.py`

The `userInformation.py` has some data which the user can manually change.
The `actualcode.py` loads the data from `userInformation.py` and processes it and gives the output.

The execution will be in this way, user enters the data in `userInformation.py` saves it and then runs `actualcode.py` and gets the output.

---

## Issue

I want to create a executable for the `actualcode.py`, which I am able to do using the command : `pyinstaller --onefile actualcode.py`

However, while building the exe, pyinstaller also loads the `userInformation.py` file and bundles it with the executable, so now even if the user makes changes to the `userInformation.py` file, they are not loaded/reflected when he runs the `actualcode.py` as the file is already loaded in the *exe*.

I want to know if there any better way to do this.

Would loading the data in a *dotenv* file instead of the `userInformation.py` solve my problem ?

Or are there any parameters in pyinstaller which will help me build executable on actualcode.py and still load the data from userInformation.py

Also is there a way to build a *parameterized exe* with python? In that case I would just call the exe with the data parameters instead of using a different file?

Comment: For example this is what my code would look like

file userInformation.py
a=1
b=2


file actualcode.py
import userInformation
print(int(userInformation.a)+int(userInformation.b))

and I want to build a exe on actualcode.py which can then refer to the userInformation.py and I can update and change the numbers in userInformation.py and run the exe and it would add the updated numbers and give the output.

Comment: Is there any reason your data have to be in a .py file ? Cannot you read them from a text file for instance ?

Comment: That would work to. If I save it in a text file would my exe access the text file, load the new data and process ?

Comment: If I use the " imp " module in my actualcode.py and write code to  load the data from text file (temp.txt) using imp.loadsource and then build the exe on actualcode.py would that exe still load fresh data from the text file everytime it runs ?

Comment: Answering not the latest command: If your read the data from the file yes. I mean it will require some changes in your code to read the text file and use the values. You may also be interested in the configparser module

Comment: You could also try adding --exclude-module=userInformation.py to your build command. Then the module will not be embedded to your exe and you will be able to import it at run time. Never tried it though

Comment: loading the information from a text file instead of a .py file resolved the issue.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use JSON if you don't want to. You can just change the userInformation.py script to save all the informations in a .txt file. And change the actualcode.py script to get the information from the .txt file. You will have to make two .exe files. One for the manipulating the user information and the actual file which does something.

Hope that helps!

Comment: tried to store it in text file helped, this solved my pupose.



file = open('info.txt','r')
contents = file.read()
d = {}
d=contents.split('\n')
print(d)

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON for example, rather than using python script itself as mean of data storaging.

Here's some demonstration you can play with.

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

relative_loc = "./file_data.json"


def write():
    # create some data to save
    some_list = [i for i in range(3)]
    some_dict = {i: n for i, n in enumerate(range(0, 6, 2))}
    some_name = [i * 2 for i in 'abcd']

    to_file = {"list": some_list,
               "dict": some_dict,
               "name": some_name}
    
    # saving to json
    with open(relative_loc, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(to_file, f, indent=2)


def read():
    # reading json
    with open(relative_loc, 'r') as f:
        file = json.load(f)
    
    # Do something to file - just printing for this demo.
    pprint(file)


write()
read()
```

file output:

```
{
  "list": [
    0,
    1,
    2
  ],
  "dict": {
    "0": 0,
    "1": 2,
    "2": 4
  },
  "name": [
    "aa",
    "bb",
    "cc",
    "dd"
  ]
}
```

Read Result:

```
{'dict': {'0': 0, '1': 2, '2': 4},
 'list': [0, 1, 2],
 'name': ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd']}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

---

To add, if you are planning to use PyInstaller with `--onefile` flag, you get a **packed** exe that is unpacked to TEMP directory when you execute it.

That makes working directory to TEMP directory. All relative path will be broken if so.

This is actual cause of issue that changes made on `userInformation.py` not reflected - as `userInformation.py` inside onefile exe is unzipped at TEMP directory every time you run it.

If you want to use onefile option - you need to change working directory like this:

```
def IsFrozen():
    """
    Checks whether Python instance is Frozen(aka onefile) or not.
    Change directory if needed.
    """
    if getattr(sys, "frozen", False):
        return

    file_dir = os.path.dirname(sys.argv[0])
    
    try:
        os.chdir(file_dir)
    except OSError:  # Fail-safe
        pass
```

This way your scripts will find files placed with *exe* file, but **not** modules that are always imported on so-called ["import time"](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=kYZHCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA688&lpg=PA688&dq=python%20importtime%20runtime&source=bl&ots=isDgYxATOk&sig=ACfU3U3vwLCjT14N4MOeL6WTQ6Q-wjYLgA&hl=ko&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiziqHE57PqAhUaK6YKHVM6DhsQ6AEwAHoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=python%20importtime%20runtime&f=false).

Comment: JSON would make my code more complex.
I just saved the information from userInformation.py in a text file and tried to create a exe and it helped solve my problem

Thank you for your explanation though. Helpful !

Comment: Good enough, just make sure you know that there is json module - so in the future you can utilize it for your bigger project.